# Cannot resolve symbol in multiple places

Tags: android

I've started learning android development in android studio and was doing this [tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/). I followed the steps and copied the code but when I got to the end I had the errors

"Cannot resolve symbol 'main'", "Cannot resolve symbol 'horizontal'" and "Cannot resolve symbol 'vertical'" in my main.java file. I will add the code below and comment where the errors occur but does any one know how to fix this?

```
package com.example.fujitsu.test3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Main extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    private float mLastX, mLastY, mLastZ;
    private boolean mInitialized; private SensorManager mSensorManager; private Sensor mAccelerometer; private final float NOISE = (float) 2.0;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);                       //ERROR HERE
    mInitialized = false;
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
// can be safely ignored for this demo
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    TextView tvX= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.x_axis);
    TextView tvY= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.y_axis);
    TextView tvZ= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.z_axis);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];
    if (!mInitialized) {
        mLastX = x;
        mLastY = y;
        mLastZ = z;
        tvX.setText("0.0");
        tvY.setText("0.0");
        tvZ.setText("0.0");
        mInitialized = true;
    } else {
        float deltaX = Math.abs(mLastX - x);
        float deltaY = Math.abs(mLastY - y);
        float deltaZ = Math.abs(mLastZ - z);
        if (deltaX < NOISE) deltaX = (float)0.0;
        if (deltaY < NOISE) deltaY = (float)0.0;
        if (deltaZ < NOISE) deltaZ = (float)0.0;
        mLastX = x;
        mLastY = y;
        mLastZ = z;
        tvX.setText(Float.toString(deltaX));
        tvY.setText(Float.toString(deltaY));
        tvZ.setText(Float.toString(deltaZ));
        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (deltaX > deltaY) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.horizontal);  //ERROR HERE
        } else if (deltaY > deltaX) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.vertical);   //ERROR HERE
        } else {
            iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Cannot resolve `R.layout.main` means that the system expects there to be a layout named `main.xml` in your `res/layout` folder.

`R.drawable.*` means you need some drawable  resources like images, etc. under your `res/drawable` folder.

You probably haven't copied those from the tutorial. Those are mentioned in step 1 and step 3 of that tutorial :)  Do that and you'll be golden.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! I did not think of the pictures at all! They were downloaded under different names and I just assumed they were fine! I fixed those errors but now I'm getting errors saying R cannot be resolved? Do you know anything about this?

Comment: It depends. If you have made mistakes in your XML, it will stop the creation of `R`. Check for errors :)

Comment: It does not give me any but I'll try find some. Thank you again for your help! :)

Comment: Press CTRL + SHIFT + O if you are using Eclipse. It will import it for you.

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot resolve symbol 'horizontal,vertical'

`vertical` and `horizontal` is images. issue is occurring because images are not found in `res/drawable-mdpi` folder.

To fix issue all all images in `res/drawable-mdpi` folder

> Cannot resolve symbol 'main'

`main` is layout file issue is occurring because `main` is not found inside `res/layout` folder

Create a layout with name of `main.xml` with all views which want to show in `Main` Activity

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I managed to fix those errors but now it is saying it cannot resolve symbol R. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @Calturk: just close->reopen->Clean current project. after that if using eclipse IDE then press `CTRL+SHIFT+O` to fix all import related issues

Comment: I had tried this before a few times but now it's working, but I'm not complaining :P Thank you very much for your help, it is working now :)